# What are external tools for testing thread safety in Ruby and Rails?

Tags: ruby

It's rather annoying to determine thread safety entirely by eye.  Surely people make mistakes...

It would be nice to find a tool that can automate the checking for non-thread-safe code in Ruby and catch thread-unsafe code that might be missed by eye.  I know some exist in other languages, such as this one in Java.  http://thread-safe.org/.  And automated checking has been written for practically every other aspect of Ruby code.  But I haven't been able to find any automated checkers for the thread safety of Ruby code.